# Probability of Lie Detector

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> The following stats are given about lie detectors:
>
> When a person tells the truth sometimes the lie detector will show a positive test 10% of the time.
>
> Meanwhile when a person is lying the lie detector will show a positive test 90% of the time
>
> Three different people are tested:
>
> One lies everytime they are asked a question, another lies 70 percent and the last person only lies 10 percent.
>
> 1. What is the probability that a positive test is shown for all three people?  What about a negative test for all three?
>
> 2. What is the probability the lie detector shows a positive test on the person that lies constantly and a negative test on the other two people?
>
> 3. Given that the lie detector showed a positive test on exactly two people, what is the probability those two people were the person that lies all the time and the one that lies 70% of the time?
>
> 4. Given that the third person told the truth, what is the probability the lie detector gave him a false positive test?

So I have some work for three of the four questions but not sure if I am correct.  #3 I am not sure how to start.

For #1 I said since there is three people and the probability the test is positive, we will call P and a person is lying, we will call N is $P(P|L)=.9$ and $P(P|L^c)=.1$ so I did $(P(P|L)P(P|L^c))^3=.00729$ and for all tests being negative I did the same thing except I did $((1-P(P|L))(1-P(P|L^c)))^3$ and got the same answer as before so I feel like this isn't correct.

For #2 I did (I added the notation $L1, L2, L3$.  $L1$ for the 1st person probabilty of lying, L2 being the 2nd person probabilty of lying, etc.) $(P(P|L1)P(P|L2^c)(P(P|L3^c))$=(.9)($\frac{1}{3}$)($\frac{1}{9}$)=$\frac{1}{30}$.

For #4 I did $P(P|L3^c)$=$\frac{1}{9}$

Again #3 I wasn't sure about and the other questions I answered I am not sure I was going in the right direction.

Comment: The title of your question does not represent the content. I suggest you edit the title for people to see that its a question about probability.

Answer (score 1):

Call these 3 people A, B, and C.  Imagine 1000 such situations.  A lies all the time so, since "when a person is lying the lie detector will show a positive test 90% of the time", in 900 cases the lie detector returns a "positive" result (A is lying) and in 100 cases returns a "negative" result (A is telling the truth). The probability the lie detector returns "positive" is 0.90 and the probability the lie detector returns "negative" is 1- 0.90= 0.10.

B lies 70% of the time and the lie detector returns a "positive" result .7(.9)= 0.63 or 63% of the time so in 630 of the 1000 cases, and a "negative" result in 370 of the 1000 cases.  The probability the lie detector returns "positive" is 0.63 and the probability the lie detector returns "negative" is 1- 0.63= 0.37.

C lies 30% of the time and the lie detector returns a "positive" result .3(.9)= 0.27 or 27% of the time so in 270 of the 1000 cases, and a "negative" result in 730 or the 1000 cases. The probability the lie detector returns "positive" is 0.75 and the probability the lie detector returns "negative" is 1- 0.75= 0.25.

The probability that all three tests return "positive" is (0.90)(0.63)(0.75)= 0.42525.
The probability that all three tests return "negative" is (.10)(0.37)(0.25)= 0.00925.

The probability the lie detector returns "positive" on A is 0.90 and the probability it returns "negative" on both B and C is (0.37)(0.25)= 0.0925.  The probability returns "positive" for A [b]and[/b] "negative" for both B and C is (0.9)(0.0925)= 0.08325.

The probability the test returns "positive" for both A and B and negative for C is (0.9)(0.63)(0.25)= 0.14175.
The probability the test returns "positive" for both A and C and negative for B is (0.9)(0.37)(0.75)= 0.24975.
The probability the test return "positive" for both B and C and negative for C is (0.1)(0.63)(0.75)= 0.04725.

So the probability or "positive" on two and "negative" on the other is 0.14175+ 0.24975+ 0.04725= 0.43875.  The probability that A and B were the two lying was 0.14175 so the probability that "given that the test showed two people lying and one person telling the truth, the probability that it was A and B lying" is 0.14175/0.43875= 0.3231.

"4. Given that the third person told the truth, what is the probability the lie detector gave him a false positive test?"
I don't understand this.  "Given that the third person told the truth" there [I]can't[/I] be a [B]false[/b] positive!  I would say the probability of a "false positive test" is 0 but I doubt that is what they meant.  Perhaps the problem was supposed to be about a "false [b]negative[/b] test".  Given that the third person told the truth, and that the test returns a "false negative" 10% of the time, the person will have probability of a "false negative" of 0.10.